# An Open Interval and a Half-open Interval are not Homeomorphic

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions

As the topic, how can I prove it?

> Prove that (a,b) and [a,b) in R are not homeomorphic metric space.

I'm pretty weak on this section (homeomorphism) and I don't have any clue to figure it out.

Please help me, thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Without going into formalisms, if two spaces are homeomorphic then all of their topological properties are the same.
Now the space $(a,b)$ has the (topological) property that if you remove any of its points, the resulting space is disconnected. But the space $[a,b)$ does not have this property -- why?

Comment: because I can remove the point "a" from [a,b) and the resulting space is still connected.

Comment: I can understand this discussion, makes me more familiar to homs.
But I can't tell the professor this way.
I'll try to make this discussion into a complete proof.

Comment: By my lights, this is a complete proof.

Comment: @Lubin: Between mathematicians already familiar with topology, it’s a prefectly good high-level proof.  But in the context of, say, a first course in topology, it should probably have a few more details filled in.

Answer (score 11):

Thank to all above, now I write it this way and it seems complete.

> Suppose not, i.e. if there exist $f:(a,b) \to [a,b)$ a homeomorphism.
>
> By definition, f is continuous, $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and $f$ is bijective.
>
> $f$ is bijective then we have the inverse image of $[a,b)$ is $(a,b)$
>
> $f^{-1}(a)$ is a single point, say c, and $a \lt c \lt b$.
>
> Consider $f^{-1}((a,b))=(a,c) \cup (c,b)$ is disconnected.
>
> It contradicts the fact that $f^{-1}((a,b))$ is connected, noted that $(a,b)$ connected and $f^{-1}$ is continuous.
>
> Therefore, $(a,b)$ and $[a,b)$ are not homeomorphic.

Comment: You could have defined your function from $[a,b)$ to $(a,b)$. This way, the proof would have looked cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Let $f: [a,b) \to (a,b)$ be a homeomorphism. Then the image of $(a,b)$ is $(a,b) \setminus \{f(a)\}$. Because $(a,b)$ is connected and $f$ is continuous, the image of $(a,b)$ is connected.

Can $(a,b) \setminus \{f(a)\}$ be connected (we know that $f(a)$ is in $(a,b)$ )? Assume it is. Now $(a,b)\setminus \{f(a)\} = (a, f(a)) \cup (f(a) ,b)$. What does this mean?

Comment: (a,f(a))and(f(a),b)are disjoint nonempty open intervals (open interval at least contains an open ball) and hence separate (a,b)\{f(a)}. Then it's disconnected.