# How to check whether X and Y are homeomorphic or not?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

[image]

I am trying to find a  function $f$
Such that

1. Bijective

2)$f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous

But can't find.

Any hints?

Comment: They are not homeomorphic. This is often proven by finding a property preserved by homeomorphisms, which one space possesses and the other does not. Have you seen any proofs of that sort already? For example, have you seen any proofs that an open interval in $\mathbb R$ (say $(a,b)$) is not homeomorphic to a half-open interval (say $[a,b)$)?

Comment: Can it remove some points, one has some property, another doesn’t have? It is my guess only.

Comment: (cont'd) If you haven't, have a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054488/an-open-interval-and-a-half-open-interval-are-not-homeomorphic. Then think if you can do something similar here.